# In Nativescript the result from imageSource.fromUrl is coming as {"android":{}}

Tags: android, nativescript

While following the link [https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/image-source](http://Nativescript%20image-source), in the console, am getting the result as {"android":{}} in my android device.

Below is my js code

```
var createViewModel = require("./main-view-model").createViewModel;
var imageSource = require("image-source");

function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    imageSource.fromUrl("https://www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png")
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log("Image successfully loaded");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    }, function (error) {
        //console.log("Error loading image: " + error);
    });
    page.bindingContext = createViewModel();
}
exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;
```

Should we do anything more to get the image. Apologies if the question is too basic, just getting to know Nativescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches to load an image from URL - you can create an instance of image via code behind and attach the imageSource to its src and then dynamically added the image to a page container element (e.g. grid-layout, stack-layout or else)

Or, you can use data binding and once you get the imaageSource to bind it with your view model.

example given:

***page.js***

```
var observable_1 = require('data/observable');
var imageSource = require("image-source");

function navigatingTo(args) {

    var page = args.object;
    var viewModel = new observable_1.Observable();
    imageSource.fromUrl("https://www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png")
        .then(function (res) {

        viewModel.set("myUrl", res);
    }, function (error) {
        //console.log("Error loading image: " + error);
    });
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;
}
exports.navigatingTo = navigatingTo;
```

***page.xml***

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label text="ImageSource fromUrl example" class="title"/>
    <Image src="{{ myUrl }}" stretch="none" />
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```